# How to check for numbers that ends with 0?

Tags: python

In Python, how would I figure out if the number ends with 0 (10, 20, 30, 40)? I am implementing a system that loops through 24 hours in 24 hours format with 10 minutes intervals but no time library seems to provide time only solutions and  it seems that it requires me to input a date and time as string instead of only time.

Comment: `num % 10 == 0`

Comment: The `%` is the modulo operator. It does division and returns the *remainder*. So `35 % 3 = 5` while`40 % 10 = 0`

Comment: That's surprisingly simple, thanks guys!

Comment: Modulo, modulo, need to understand that.